# Toggle dropdown, send graphs to powerpoint and save

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, dropdown

Example Documents - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6dcbda3f91a46c957f5dbb0cb0b2deaa20190723114415/ec3fe2

I am trying to select an option from a drop down (which will change some graphs), then send graphs to a Powerpoint presentation, save the presentation and move on to the next option in the dropdown to repeat.

Getting it to do it once is ok, but I'm struggling with the repeat - I get an error

> Run-time error '70' Permission Denied

when it gets to the bit where it needs to open a powerpoint with the name of the next option on the dropdown. The error is on

```
FileCopy "K:\Data Analysis\Toxicology\Tox Customer MI" & "\" & Range("Customer_MI_Template"), PPReport_Name).
```

I think it may be because it hasn't actually selected the next dropdown option and so is a duplicate file name.

I thought at first it was because it couldn't find the file location as it was set to 'ThisWorkbook.Path' however if I change this to the actually drive and file path it still doesn't work.

I then thought it was because the next thing on my dropdown had illegal characters, however I removed these and still no.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakePowerpoint()

ThisWorkbook.Save


Dim MyPath As String
Dim FileName As String

Dim objPPT As Object
Dim ppt As Object
Dim sld As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim PPReport_Name As String
Dim DocName As String
Dim shpIndex As Long
Dim CurSlide As Long

Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ObjName As String
Dim ObjType As String
Dim PPSldNum As Long
Dim PPObjName As String
Dim MyTop As Double
Dim MyLeft As Double
Dim MyHeight As Double
Dim MyWidth As Double
Dim cl As Range
Dim OldText As String
Dim NewText As String

Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long

' which cell has data v to for each c in input from online

 'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Customer Homepage").Range("D11")
     'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)


    i = 1
     'Begin our loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In inputRange

' Set up the pathname and the output PowerPoint Presentation Name
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
PPReport_Name = MyPath & "\" & MonthName(Month(Range("D10"))) & "\" & Range("PPReport_Name")

' Copy the template file to the PowerPoint Presentation Name
***FileCopy "K:\Data Analysis\Toxicology\Tox Customer MI" & "\" & Range("Customer_MI_Template"), PPReport_Name***

' Open the PowerPoint Presentation
Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True
objPPT.presentations.Open PPReport_Name

Set ppt = objPPT.activepresentation

' Add objects
For Each cl In Range("Table_Objects[Excel Page]")
    ObjType = cl.Offset(0, 2).Value     ' Type of the thing to copy
    If ObjType <> "Text" Then
        Set sh = Sheets(cl.Value)       ' Excel Sheet
        ObjName = cl.Offset(0, 1).Value ' Name of the thing to copy
    End If

    PPSldNum = cl.Offset(0, 3).Value    ' PowerPoint slide number
    PPObjName = cl.Offset(0, 4).Value   ' PowerPoint object
    MyTop = cl.Offset(0, 5).Value       ' Top
    MyLeft = cl.Offset(0, 6).Value      ' Left
    MyHeight = cl.Offset(0, 7).Value    ' Height
    MyWidth = cl.Offset(0, 8).Value     ' Width
    OldText = cl.Offset(0, 9).Value     ' Old Text
    NewText = cl.Offset(0, 10)          ' New Text

    Set sld = ppt.slides(PPSldNum)      ' Active Slide

    Select Case ObjType
        Case "Text"
            sld.Shapes(PPObjName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
                Replace(sld.Shapes(PPObjName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, OldText, NewText)
        Case "Chart"
            sh.Shapes(ObjName).CopyPicture
        Case "Range"
            sh.Range(ObjName).CopyPicture
    End Select

    If ObjType = "Chart" Or ObjType = "Range" Then
        sld.Shapes.Paste
        shpIndex = sld.Shapes.Count
        With sld.Shapes(shpIndex)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Top = 72 * MyTop
            .Left = 72 * MyLeft
            .Height = 72 * MyHeight
            .Width = 72 * MyWidth
        End With
    End If

Next


'Next c and screenupdate true from online

Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function GetText(ObjName As String, Pos As Long) As String
Dim cl As Range
Dim Result As String

Result = "Value not found"

For Each cl In Range("Table_TextFrame[PPObjName]")
    If cl.Value = ObjName Then
        Result = cl.Offset(0, Pos).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next
GetText = Result
End Function
```

The macro will run and save a powerpoint based on whoever I select in the dropdown no problem, but then will not repeat for the next option on the dropdown.

Comment: I'd like to test for you, but this is a lot of code and of course I don't have your workbooks or anything. Could you please provide a [mcve]? It just needs enough to reproduce the problem, without any "bells and whistles".

Comment: I couldn't work out how to attach a file so hopefully the following link will let you download them - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6dcbda3f91a46c957f5dbb0cb0b2deaa20190723114415/ec3fe2 It contains the PowerPoint presentation and the Excel file too.

Comment: No, file attachments aren't allowed here, and for good reason. This is a Q&A site, not a help desk. The information here should be accessible to everyone who may have interest in the problem. Files provided externally don't meet these criteria. Please provide all relevant information *in the question*. Yes, that probably means time and extra work - but we shouldn't have to do that work, as well as look for the solution...